# Wireless network speed is slower than the maximum in Windows 7

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Dell Inspirion 5520 that has Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 built in.

Also I have a TP link TL-WR740N wireless router.

I have an 80Mbps/25MBps internet connection.

My Speedtest result with no router:

[image]

When I connect all these via an Ethernet cable, I get the maximum  even through the router:

[image]

But when I try to do the same with WiFi I get 30/20 Maximum speed, and I'm sitting next to router!

I have this configuration:

*router:*
- Channel: auto
- Mode: 11n only
- Channel width: 40Mhz
- Max Tx rate: 150Mbps
- Enabled Wireless Router Radio
- Enabled SSID Broadcast
- Security: WPA- AES
- Beacon Interval : 100
- RTS Threshold: 2346
- Fragmentation Threshold: 2346
- DTIM Interval: 1
- Enabled WMM
- Enabled Short GI

*Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230:*
- 802.11n Channel width for band 2.4 : Auto
- 802.11n Mode: enabled
- Ad Hoc Channel 802.11b/g: 1
- Ad Hoc QoS Mode: WMM enabled
- Bluetooth(R) AMP: Enabled
- Fat Channel Intolerant: Disabled
- Mixed Mode Protection: CTS-to-self Enabled
- Roaming Aggressiveness: 3. Medium
- Transit power: 5. Highest
- Wireless Mode: 802.11b/g

I do get the fact that speed through wireless is slower than with wire, but losing 50Mbps is a bit too much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Disable Bluetooth on the Centrino 2230.
2. And also set Bluetooth(R) AMP: Disabled.

Comment: thanks! this made it work! I would have not guessed that the bluetooth would interfere this much! http://speedtest.net/result/2558140781.png

Comment: how comes enabling/disabling bluetooth effects wifi transfer that much?

Comment: I thnink it's because both Bluetooth and wifi operate in the range of 2400–2483.5 MHz. So this causes interference with each other. Your microwave could also be interfering(if poorly shielded) ... see: [Electromagnetic_interference_at_2.4_GHz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference_at_2.4_GHz)

Answer (score 1):

Having G devices on your network can slow down the speed for all devices. Encryption, distance and interface can also limit your speed.

SmallNetBuilder has a couple of good articles on steps you can try:

- [Five ways to fix slow N speeds](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30664-5-ways-to-fix-slow-80211n-speed)
- [Add don't replace when upgrading to N](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-features/30224-add-dont-replace-when-upgrading-to-80211n)

Comment: I'm the only one on the router currently, and i read those articles, sadly didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

tried this:

netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled

ofc must be written as admin :)

Comment: Are you saying that you tried this yourself, or are you suggesting OP try this command? Also, spell out your words completely. "ofc" is not a word. I can guess what you mean by it, but it is not even an acronym if what I think is the case. A little more work to make it more clear WHAT you are saying would make this a much better answer.